# .click() cause scroll to the last triggered element

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have this function inside my js:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $( ".jp-playlist, .jp-play").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

            window.parent.$("iframe[id^='iframe']:not(#iframe_"+playerNumber+")").contents().find(".jp-stop").click();


    });
});
```

There is a problem in Firefox. When I click element with class `jp-play` or `jp-playlist` whole view jumping to the last element on the page which is triggered by this function. 
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What type of element are you clicking ? Most probably, the browser scrolls to the clicked element because it gains focus (elements like `<input>`, `<button>`, etc.).

Comment: @Titus Element which is clicked by function looks like that: `<button class="jp-stop" role="button" tabindex="0">stop</button>`

Comment: Try: `.....find(".jp-stop").mousedown(function(event){event.preventDefault()})` before the click to prevent that element from getting focus.

Comment: @Titus Thank your tip! I've solved problem.
There was function inside source file of jPlayer:
`function(c) { c.preventDefault(), d[b](c), d.options.autoBlur ? a(this).blur() : a(this).focus() };`  

 button `.jp-stop` was attached to this function, so I've deleted lines which caused focusing on that button. Now everything works perfect.

Comment: That is good to know, good luck